# Golang smtp.SendMail blocking

Tags: smtp, go

I tried to use `smtp.SendMail()` in a go program.
However it blocks and doesn't return until it times out.
This prevents me from finding out what is wrong.

My code:

```
to := []string{"recepient@example.com"}
err := smtp.SendMail("smtp.web.de:25", smtp.CRAMMD5Auth("example@web.de", "password"), "example@web.de", to, []byte("hi"))
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}else{
    fmt.Println("Success")
}
```

After a long time I get the following error:

```
dial tcp 213.165.67.124:25: connection timed out
```

Any ideas what might be the real problem?

Comment: How does blocking prevent you from debugging? I can't reproduce this behaviour, I get `530 Authentication required`. Have you tried tracing the traffic using a packet sniffer?

Comment: As for sniffing: It seems to use TLS, which makes me unable to see what is going on. (Wireshark reports TLSv1 Client Key exchange, etc.) As for debug: I am not sure how i can get SendMail to print what it sends/receives.

Comment: @user2089648 have a look at the `Debugging` section under http://sendmail.org/~ca/email/doc8.12/op-sh-3.html

Comment: If it's on port 25 it will be in plain text until a STARTTLS command is issued.  You're probably sniffing the wrong traffic.  In any case "connection timed out" means a specific thing - the (TCP) connection timed out, i.e. the packet isn't getting to smtp.web.de or you are not getting its reply.  Very likely not a golang issue.

Comment: suggestion - use http://mailtrap.io instead of smtp.web.de, the service gives you a free smtp server on their infrastructure with all emails being kept on the server for you to view. it's a winner for any email-testing related development..

Comment: Try net.Dial("tcp", "smtp.web.de:25"). I bet your ISP is blocking port 25.

Comment: `nc smtp.web.de 25` will tell you whether port 25 is being blocked. telnet works too.

Answer (score 2):

`SendMail` dial smtp server uses non-tls tcp connection, maybe your smtp server default uses tcp connection with ssl, not support `STARTTLS` extension. Client send `STARTTLS` commond and server will not reply, so now is blocking.

```golang
func SendMail(addr string, a Auth, from string, to []string, msg []byte) error {
    ......

    if ok, _ := c.Extension("STARTTLS"); ok {
        config := &tls.Config{ServerName: c.serverName}
        if testHookStartTLS != nil {
            testHookStartTLS(config)
        }
        if err = c.StartTLS(config); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    ......
}
```

Now you can dail smtp server with tls and this is not blocking, detail see
[example code](https://blog.iakmai.com/2017/02/28/golang_smtp/), or use non-tls port.

```golang
// SendMailTLS connects to the server at addr, default use TLS
func SendMailTLS(addr string, auth smtp.Auth, from string, to []string, msg []byte) error {
    ......
    tlsconfig := &tls.Config{ServerName: host}
    if err = validateLine(from); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    ......
    conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", addr, tlsconfig)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    c, err := smtp.NewClient(conn, host)
    ......
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing a timeout you can try using net.Dial directly to verify connectivity :

```
conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "smtp.web.de:25")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

If that is not connecting then there is something local blocking the socket. Ask you local network guys about the firewall setup or if there are any network proxy type devices intercepting the outgoing traffic.

Answer (score -4):

I'm pretty sure anything that goes by on port :25 is blocked on a router level, so you will have to change your router or server providers settings.

Comment: that's not true. port 25 is for smtp mail

Comment: It will not be allowed if they are in a residential network , if you SSH into your server and run it, then it should work I believe.

Comment: You seem to be talking bout your local setup and not a general answer for the OP